# "Let's back to page 3", "Let's go back to page 3" or both?

Tags: verbs, vocabulary, error

I recently started learning Chinese and my teachers use English as a second language. I noticed that many of them use the phrase "Let's back to (page XYZ)" as opposed to "Let's go back to (page XYZ)". I had been speaking English for about 20 years so far and never stumbled upon this phrase, but [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/back#Verb) says it's a valid verb:

> (intransitive) To go in the reverse direction. quotations ▼
>
> the train backed into the station;  the horse refuses to back

So, is "go" needed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Let's" behaves like a modal, and always requires a verb (in the infinitive, or base form.

"Let's back to page 3" is not grammatical in any variety of English that I am aware of.

"Back" can be a verb, but I've only ever heard it in the sense of (physically) moving backwards, not just meaning "go back". It doesn't make sense in that example.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, *back* as a verb can also mean "to support", as in "Rogers backed Smith for chairman", but your general point is quite correct.

Comment: I considered mentioning that, @stangdon, and decided it would just confuse matters for no benefit.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/back), **back** as a verb can mean **to (cause to) move backwards**. I would only use this word to mean reversing a vehicle.

If I were to talk about moving my own body backwards, I would say **go back**. Similarly, if I were talking about returning to pages in a book that I have already read, I would say **go back**.

Comment: I can imagine "Let's back up to page 3" as an alternative.

Comment: @J.R. I can imagine an American saying that, but I (BrE) probably wouldn't for a book- only for a vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

Back can be a verb, but most of its definitions have nothing to do with "go back". The most similar meaning is to "go back" is to move/make something backwards and the structure is obviously different - it is typically

back (verb) + *noun* + *preposition*

rather than

back (verb) + *preposition*

Therefore, I don't think your teacher used a correct expression.